# "The property Query contains an invalid value." - I can't see it

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, caml, spsitedataquery

```
query.Query = @"<Where>
<And>
<BeginsWith>
<FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId'/>
<Value Type='Text'>[LONG GUID]</Value>
</BeginsWith>
<And>
<Geq>
<FieldRef Name='PublishingStartDate' />
<Value Type='DateTime'>2011-01-01T15:55:52Z</Value>
</Geq>
<Leq>
<FieldRef Name='PublishingStartDate' />
<Value Type='DateTime'>2011-01-01T15:55:52Z</Value>
</Leq>
</And>
</And>
</Where>
<OrderBy>
<FieldRef Name='PublishingStartDate' Ascending='FALSE' />
</OrderBy>";
```

The above query is attempting to bring back all items of a certain content type between two dates and order (descending) by the same date field.

EDIT: I should mention that this is an SPSiteDataQuery

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the OrderBy clause - can anyone see a problem with it? (field definitely exists).

Comment: I see two root elements `Where` and `OrderBy`

Comment: I didn't think this mattered when assigning it to a Query property (i.e. the query property encloses all of this string in <Query> tags so that there's in effect only 1 by the time the query's ran?) I may be wrong, I'm new to this. What do you propose? +1.

Comment: @Daniel Having `Where` and `OrderBy` as "twin" root elements here is fine.

Comment: I thought so. Thanks Rawling. Could the problem be that it's trying to order the results but there are none (I can confirm that this query yields 0 results)? I doubt it, but I can't think of anything else.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your CAML. All I can suggest is, try it with some records returned (use different dates?), with and without the OrderBy clause, see what happens.

Comment: I will try that, but it's not really acceptable that it would raise an exception when there are no results. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see anything wrong in your CAML. One thing I noticed is the value of the PublishingStartDate filter values. Both Geq and Leq are having exactly the same date time value.

```
<Geq>
<FieldRef Name='PublishingStartDate' />
<Value Type='DateTime'>2011-01-01T15:55:52Z</Value>
</Geq>
<Leq>
<FieldRef Name='PublishingStartDate' />
<Value Type='DateTime'>2011-01-01T15:55:52Z</Value>
</Leq>
```

Are you sure that both filter should be using the same date time?

Comment: +1 for that Senthil, thanks. To be honest it's demo data for now for the sake of this thread but you'd have been spot on if it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late to answer this, but for further reference: the problem is that you can't have new line symbols in the query or view felds.
I had the same problem - if you put all of CAML on one row, it will work.